# Convert string to int for sum in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a column `requestAmount` that is `nvarchar(100)`.

I need to calculate sum :

```
int? sum = q.Sum(g => g.requestAmount);
```

I got this error:

> Error 26 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   '`System.Func<samtaApplication.DbLayer.tblMaterial,int>`' because some
>   of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the
>   delegate return type

How can I convert string to int?

Comment: it's nice to know that requestAmount is nvarchar(100), but as you're in an c# object world, you can just say that it's a string ;)

Comment: Enumerable.Sum never returns null. So are you sure you need a `Nullable<int>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int? sum = q.Sum(g => Int32.Parse(g.requestAmount));
```

Answer (score 5):

In **linq to entities** you can always materialize query first, so you will operate on linq to objects

```
int? sum = q.AsEnumerable().Sum(g => Int.Parse(g.requestAmount));
```

Note that it will load whole `q` from db

EDIT:

if `requestAmount` is nullable then use:

```
int? sum = q.AsEnumerable().Sum(g => Convert.ToInt32(g.requestAmount));
```

`Convert.ToInt32` will return 0 when null is passed as parameter

Comment: Hmmm, and if requestAmount is null ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus there is no information about nullability of this field. If it's nullable nvarchar then we need to use Convert.ToInt32

Comment: Well, for your second version, sum whill never be null, so why use a `Nullable<int>`. Question is not clear on this point, you're right.

Comment: Anyway, Enumerable.Sum never returns null... So the second version is perfectly valid...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yeah, only way to return null will be making some if statement and checking if all values are null -> return null / else count sum of non-null values

Answer (score 2):

A `string` can be null or empty, so, keep it safe using a filter with `Where` and after it applying and `Sum` , for sample:

```
int dummy;
int result = q.Where(g => int.TryParse(g.TryParse(g.requestAmount, out dummy))
              .Sum(g => int.Parse(g.requestAmount.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the int.TryParse?