# convert type string to long in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i want to convert string to long, can anyone help me .
thank you in advance .

```
List<ViewAttendenceReport> viewAttendenceReports = new List<ViewAttendenceReport>();
EmployeeAttendenceBLL aEmployeeAttendenceBll = new EmployeeAttendenceBLL();
viewAttendenceReports = aEmployeeAttendenceBll.ViewAttendenceReportDetaitlsInOut(stDate, endDate);


viewAttendenceReports.Add(new ViewAttendenceReport()
{
      EmployeeName = "Total: ",
      TotalWorkingHours = viewAttendenceReports.Count > 0 ? viewAttendenceReports.Sum(a => a.TotalWorkingHours.ToString()) : 0    
});

allAttendenceDataGridView.DataSource = viewAttendenceReports;
```

Comment: What is the type of TotalWorkingHours and why are you calling ToString on it?

Comment: it is type string

Comment: i want to total employee totalworking hour sum.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: So `.Sum(a => Convert.ToInt64(a.TotalWorkingHours))`?

Comment: how to convert string to long for lamda expression.

Comment: Are you using entityframework? If yes which version? What message do you get after running the code? what does'nt work?

Comment: Also please tell us if you are trying to perform a Sum on a string?! what is the datatype of TotalWorkingHours?

Answer (score 2):

You question is not clear, but you said that you want to "convert string to long"

In order to Convert string to long inside a linqtoentities query you could use:

```
Convert.ToInt64(YourFieldName)
```

My best guess from your code is that the datatype of the field `TotalWorkingHours` is string and you want to convert that to long so that you could be able to perform a `Sum` on that field. And in the end you want to convert the result of sum to string to set it to the `TotalWorkingHours` field. If that is the case then you could use the following code to achieve that:

```
viewAttendenceReports.Add(new ViewAttendenceReport()
{
      EmployeeName = "Total: ",
      TotalWorkingHours = viewAttendenceReports.Count > 0 ? viewAttendenceReports.Sum(a => Convert.ToInt64(a.TotalWorkingHours)).ToString() : 0    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to sum the numbers with string type like "1","10","20"... you could use `Int32.Parse()`/`Int64.Parse()` instead:

```
viewAttendenceReports.Add(new ViewAttendenceReport()
{
    EmployeeName = "Total: ",
    TotalWorkingHours = viewAttendenceReports.Count > 0 ? viewAttendenceReports.Sum(a => Int64.Parse(a.TotalWorkingHours)) : 0    
});
```

Refer to

[Convert string to int for sum in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375437/convert-string-to-int-for-sum-in-linq)

[Accepted style for long vs Int64 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152868/accepted-style-for-long-vs-int64-in-c)